# How does one create a graphics application using Javascript - but without the browser?

Tags: javascript, graphics

Is there an environment to do Javascript development (besides a browser) where the application is graphical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very rare requirement, but there are things out there for this, just the maturity level is a question:

https://github.com/philogb/v8-gl/

Basically many possibilities haven been opened up since google's wonderful work on V8 JS engine, graphics being one of them.